# dart, polymer build failure, can'tfind polymer/polymer.dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I have a project that was building fine a few days ago, since then I haven't changed my dart-sdk or any library dependencies or update dart editor to my knowledge, I just made a very small change to one of my polymer elements to use paper-buttons instead of standard buttons, [the change can be seen here](https://github.com/0xor1/purity_stopwatch_example/commit/cdf860ee5de0ec96d5a0453888db72d6e3d91893)
Now when I run pub build I get the following errors, and I have no idea why, if I look in packages polymer/polymer.dart does exist and dart editor doesn't show any warnings in the project. similarly if I undo my latest changes and go back to my last working version I still get this exact same error, so I'm not sure how to debug this, any hints would be much appreciated.

```
Can't read 'package:polymer/polymer.dart' (Could not find asset polymer|lib/polymer.dart.).
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such weird problems it's often a good idea to try `pub cache repair`.

I found an open issue with the same error message: http://dartbug.com/20285

Check if `pub get` or `pub upgrade` show some warnings, errors, ...

Comment: i should really just try pub cache repair before I ask any question on here... it seems to be the fix all button